# Inconsistent Errors: Wrap / Errors - Unwrap / fmt.Errorf(%w)

Tags: go, error-handling

There seems to be an inconsistency between wrapping an error using `fmt.Errorf` with `%w` and using `errors.Wrap`:

```golang
    e1 := errors.New("error1")
    efmt := fmt.Errorf("error2: %w", e1)
    eerr := errors.Wrap(e1, "error2")

    fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(efmt))       // error1
    fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(efmt) == e1) // true
    fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(eerr))       // error2: error1
    fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(eerr) == e1) // false :-(
```

A full example is available [here](https://go.dev/play/p/rXM-Ldb4GKZ)

I am not sure whether that is intended, but this seem inconsistent... Is there a reason for that? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the intended working, and this does not violate the docs. Multiple errors may be wrapped in a single `error` value, and since a call to `Unwrap()` returns a single error, obviously not getting what you expect doesn't mean the expected error is not wrapped.

The `errors` package is from the standard lib. It does not have an `errors.Wrap()` function. The one you're using is from [`github.com/pkg/errors.Wrap()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#Wrap), which does "double-wrapping" under the hood.

First it wraps the error with the given error message, then it wraps again to retain the stack information:

```
// Wrap returns an error annotating err with a stack trace
// at the point Wrap is called, and the supplied message.
// If err is nil, Wrap returns nil.
func Wrap(err error, message string) error {
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }
    err = &withMessage{
        cause: err,
        msg:   message,
    }
    return &withStack{
        err,
        callers(),
    }
}
```

When you call `Unwrap()`, then the error from second wrapping will be returned (which is not the original error, but a wrapped error wrapping the original), calling `Unwrap()` again would return the original error.

```
fmt.Println("Double unwrap:",
    errors.Unwrap(errors.Unwrap(err2wrp)) == err1)
```

That's why you should use `errors.Is()` to avoid such "quirks":

```
fmt.Println("Proper use:", errors.Is(err2wrp, err1))
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/UxaoRugIlHH).

Note that the above reports `true` whether you call [`github.com/pkg/errors.Is()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#Is) or the standard lib's [`errors.Is()`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is).